# How do authors gain strong familiarity with archaic and extremely rare words?

Tags: vocabulary

I keep thinking about this because I've lately been reading *Blood Meridian* by Cormac McCarthy, and it's just ridiculous. I have to look up 1-2 words per sentence sometimes, something I'm only used to doing for Joyce. Apparently McCarthy is well known for doing this sort of thing.

The book was written in the mid-1980s -- it's modern. But the terms used therein belong to another time, and are mostly unknown to modern English.

How do authors pick up such a broad vocabulary of words that they can effectively disguise themselves as a hundred years older than they are? These words can't be used in day-to-day speech; nobody would understand you. If you can't use them, how do you remember them?

Examples from *Blood Meridian*: rebozo, shellalegh, hackamore, osnaburg, bungstarter, weskit, jacal, farrier, escopeta, caesura. Not a single one of these words have I ever heard reference to *anywhere else* in my entire tour of existence.

Comment: I've always found The Phrontistery to be fun: http://www.phrontistery.info

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read a lot of archaic and extremely rare books, take notes, and make a point of using your list as a thesaurus. Practice using your list by writing paragraphs or stories as exercises just to get used to where the words fit.

Comment: Can you suggest some good titles?

Comment: Depends. What do you define as "archaic and extremely rare"? I haven't read Cormac McCarthy so I don't know what words he uses that you're looking up.

Comment: I'm afraid to name any. You might just be like *Ah ha ha but I am the Lauren Ipsum and this is a word I use daily over breakfast.*

Comment: @Aerovistae like "defenestrate"? I love that one. :) I promise not to cackle at anything you ask about.

Comment: I agree that the only way to expand your vocabulary is by reading lots of words. But perhaps reading annotated versions of very old books might be a better, more educational way to do this?

Comment: @Aerovistae - Maybe Lauren reads a well-thumbed volume of the OED each day over breakfast? We just don't know, *can't* possibly know. :)

Comment: @NeilFein The Oxford American Writer's Thesaurus, actually. I save the OED for lunch.

Comment: Examples forthcoming. No time now, will be back tonight.

Comment: Alright, here we go. Examples edited into question.

Comment: @Aerovistae The horse-related words (hackamore, farrier) I know from sword-and-sorcery novels. Caesura is a musical term (I took one year of clarinet). Shillalegh is the staff leprechauns carry. :) The rest: some are trade-specific (bungstarter) or ethnic (rebozo, jacal) and you're right, some are just esoteric. It could be that McCarthy found them deliberately for his book, or that he traveled a lot and absorbed them from locals. (cont'd)

Comment: @Aerovistae If your goal is "I want to expand my vocabulary specifically with old words," then start looking for books published hundreds of years ago. I don't have a specific set of titles to recommend. But keep in mind that the same thing may happen to *your* readers: they are constantly running to the dictionary. Once or twice is fine for me; more than that and it ruins the flow of the book. Your example of *Blood Meridian* would make me put it down out of frustration. (cont'd)

Comment: @Aerovistae If your goal is "I want to expand my vocabulary, period," then pick up a Word-a-Day calendar or a thesaurus and just practice working your new words into a writing exercise.

Comment: I can't believe you know hackamore and farrier. You're unnatural.

Comment: @Aerovistae, _farrier_ is a common word.

Comment: @msh210 So is *enthalpy*, if you're into chemistry.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to expand your vocabulary is to read a lot of books with unfamiliar words in them, experiencing them in context. However, there are ways to make this easier:

- Seeking out relatively modern authors who have a reputation for using their rich vocabularies well in-context will make these words' meanings at least somewhat plain. (Gene Wolfe is my favorite writer along these lines.)
- Reading older books with unfamiliar words will give you a larger number of new words to learn, but more words to look up. Reading these books on an e-reader will help, where looking up a word isn't much more complicated than tapping it on the screen.
- Read annotated versions of older books. These will have explanations of concepts and words unfamiliar to a modern audience.

Lastly, you can move outside of reading books and go to reference sources directly:

- Browsing dictionaries and thesauri can be a heady if addictive pastime. I don't recommend this to any but the most ardent reference junkies. (Ahem.)
- There are books *about* compiling reference books that may be more digestible. For example, [Reading the OED](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0399535055) is a reader's journal of reading the entire Oxford English Dictionary.
- Word-a-day calendars can be fun. Similarly, the [Dictionary.com](https://twitter.com/dictionarycom) and the [Merriam-Webster](https://twitter.com/MerriamWebster) Twitter feeds perform similar functions.

Answer (score 2):

It may have been written in the mid 1980's but the setting is the in the mid 1800's - you really *should* expect some archaic, unusual and unfamiliar words in any book set in that timeframe. Particularly so if the dialogue is intended to accurately reflect that of colloquial speech of the time.

Your primary question can be answered in one word: research. Any book set in a historical context and intended to accurately reflect speech of that timeframe will use archaic and unfamiliar words to modern English. It's deliberate.

Answer (score 1):

I've just written a story of around 7000 words that I set in 1611, in a monastery, so wanted to use the old English terms of the day, like 'ye, thou, thee, etc.'
Gaining familiarity with these terms was only done by looking at lots of information about it, and repeating the phrases like 'Where art thou" to make it more familiar to myself, and therefore correct, for this story.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the best way to improve your vocabulary is to read widely.  But I also like subscribing to the [OED Word of the Day](http://public.oed.com/aspects-of-english/english-in-use/why-the-oeds-word-of-the-day-is-special/) email service.  I save the off-beat words in a list, like kimet (foolish or stupid), psithurisma (whispering, whispering noise), psychopomp (guide to the underworld), nemophilist (person fond of woods or forests), melliferous (yielding or producing honey), preterhuman (outside the bounds of what is human), and timeous (prompt).